# AWS Serverless in not accepting multiple variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

When you have a couple of routes which contain variables, you have to have same variable names if the prefix of the routes is the same. For instance, if  I have `test/{var1}` and `test/{var2}` the serverless returns sibling error which means that you have to have same variable names at the end of the routes. However, sometimes the different routes are responsible for the different business logic and having the same name results confusion.

The problem is already reported in serverless and it's still open issue but do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

test/{var1} and test/{var2} are the same route

either put them on different routes or split the code based on the var received

in python

```
@route('/test/{myvar}')
def name_builder(myvar):
    if myvar == "1":
       # do case 1 here
    if myvar == "2":
       # do case 2 here
```

Comment: Thanks, it could be an idea. I just fixed it by renaming them to the same general variable and handle them internally. Let see the when the serverless will manage to fix this issue.